# python 'lxml' parsing html, getting data by xpath does not work

Tags: selenium, xpath, lxml, lxml.html

I have a web page that I am fetching with a Python library: 'selenium-requests' GET method.

```
response = self.driver.request('GET', url)
```

`response.content` is the byte representation of the returned HTML.

---

In the browser (Chrome) I am using a browser plugin called 'xpath-finder' to find the xpath to a data field (text).

I have also opened up the page in Firefox and I get the same xpath.  I am confident that the xpath is correct.

I get the HTML and then need to extract the data using xpath.

---

```
import lxml

def extract_data(self, html_bytes):     # passing:  response.content (bytes)
    xpath_geocode = "/html/body/div[5]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]"
    tree = lxml.html.fromstring(html_bytes)
    geocode_info = tree.xpath(xpath_geocode)

    print('geocode_info:', geocode_info)  # this prints: geocode_info: []  <== nada

    # in fact nothing is there at all, this does not enter the for loop, and prints nothing
    for e in tree.xpath(xpath_geocode):
        print(e.text_content)
```

I have the correct xpath, I don't believe that two methods, producing the same xpath are wrong (Chrome browser plugin, and Firefox inspect, right click, copy xpath).

What am I doing wrong here?

---

could it be that:

`tree = lxml.html.fromstring(html_bytes)`

changes the html, such that the xpath is no longer valid?
If so, how do I make it so the HTML does not change?

Or how can I get the right xpath from 'tree', or find it? (through printing out etc).

Comment: It will be hard to answer without knowing what `html_bytes` looks like.

Comment: html_bytes is just the HTML returned from GET.  I understand that you want to look at it to verify that the xpath is correct, I have stated that I have used multiple methods to find the xpath, and all return the same thing.  What can be derived from the HTML beyond verifying the xpath?  If I use Selenium `self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath), it works, but the same xpath will not work used in the example above.  Why does it work with Selenium, but xpath fails?

Comment: If you're sure the xpath is correct, then it's very likely lxml. There's probably a bug in the library and it mangles the `response` sometimes; I've seen it before. I've handled it by switching to beautifulsoup, but there I have to use css selectors and `find()` methods because it doesn't support xpath.